# Rails map unique dates and render accordingly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some records with dateTime timestamps, I wish to get unique dates from them and render events in each day
Basically:

Lets say I have events with dates: january 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, I need to get unique - 1, 4, 5, 7
Then I wish to render events in these dates like so:

January 1

- Event name

January 4

- Event name
- Event name
- Event name

January 5

- Event name

Event name etc.
I have a method but this is making call to database each time it loops

```
- events.select(:start_time).collect{ |i|  i.start_time.to_date }.uniq.each do |e|
  %br= e
  = render events.where(start_time: e..e.end_of_day)
```

To better understand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFiKD.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `group_by` [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

So you could say:

```rb
- events.group_by {|event| event.start_time.to_date }.each do |start_time, events_for_date|
  %br= start_time
  = render events_for_date
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, this is now working great, renders partial on group